# Proving that any given element $hk$ appears $|H \cap K|$ times as a product in the list of $HK$

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

I have been trying to prove that if $H, K$ are finite subgroups of $G$ then $|HK|=\dfrac{|H| |K|}{|H \cap K|}$. I saw the proofs in Herstein and Gallian textbook and they are essentially the same. However, it confuses me. The claim is that any given element $hk$ appears $|H \cap K|$ times as a product in the list of $HK$ and what follows is my attempt of the proving the same but in a little different way and I wonder if it is correct.

---

We define the set $\mathcal{R}(hk)=\{ (h',k') \in H\times K \, | \, hk=h'k' \}$. Now, we define the map $f\colon H\cap K \to \mathcal{R}(hk)$ by $f(x)=(hx, x^{-1}k)$. Clearly, $f$ is well defined and we will show that $f$ is bijective.

Let $x,y \in H\cap K$ and suppose that $f(x)=f(y)$. Then $(hx, x^{-1}k)=(hy, y^{-1}k)$ and hence $x=y$.

Let $(h' , k') \in \mathcal{R}(hk)$. Then $hk=h'k'$ and let $x = h^{-1} h' = kk'^{-1}$. Clearly, $x\in H \cap K$ and we have that $h'=hx$ and $k'=x^{-1}k$. Thus, $f(x)=(h',k')$. This shows $f$ is surjective.

Hence, we have that $|\mathcal{R}(hk)|=|H \cap K|$. This proves our claim.

---

I wonder if this is okay. Are Herstein and Gallian doing the same thing?

Here's the proof from Herstein:
[image]

Comment: We cannot compare your proof with Herstein and Gallian's version, unless you post their proof here.  Not everybody has the book.  But from where I stand, your proof looks ok.

Comment: @Zvi i have updated the question

Comment: Yes, your proof and the textbook's proof are doing the same thing, phrased differently.